# Changing Year Specifically in date()

Tags: php, date

I wish to do an operation on a given date string which needs to change the year of that date to, let's say, 2000. Is there a way to accomplish this feat using PHP's date()?

```
$old_date = '2017-05-05';
// Needs to change 2017 to 2000. 
$new_date = ?
```

I know one method involves using strtotime($old_date. '-17 years') but its not applicable in every case, such as 2018 which will become 2001. Is there an alternate solution that avoids hardcoding the number of years to subtract?

**NOTE:** I'm assigning a date string to $old_date for convenience. The actual date is fetched from a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract years after millennium

```
strtotime($old_date . ' -' . date('y', strtotime($old_date)) . 'years')
```

Comment: This one is good actually. I will see if there is another solution. If not I shall mark this as correct.

Comment: @arjunsreekumar In any case, was glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = strtotime($old_date);
$year = 2000;
$new_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', $time), date('j', $time), $year));
```